# Default location change for npm bin

Tags: command-line, npm

I want to change the `npm bin` and `npm bin -g` locations.
How can I do that from the command line?
When `npm` is installed, the package prefers a location other than `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Found that the option for editing path in ~/.npmrc file. type open ~/.npmrc in terminal and edit prefix variable.

Comment: Minor adjustments to the grammar to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

`$-g/npmrc` or `-c/npmrc`

`-g` =global

`-C` =prefix

refer this link https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#command-line-flags